# Do I need the project test to be accepted into the app store?

Tags: ios

I saw that there was a project test in the application right at the bottom of the page, Do i need to have that file to be able to be accepted in iTunes and what is that by the way?

How do I remove it if needed?

And lastly both the files are highlighted red, is that normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need the Test project to submit your app to Apple. It is merely added for your convenience since most projects need some amount of unit testing. But it's purely optional. You can remove it either from Xcode or Finder.

And yes, it's OK for items under the "Products" section to be red. That just means that the product(s) haven't been built yet. You can ignore that. They will turn from red to black after you deploy to device or Archive the project later.

Comment: Cool, and the Test project had errors, I cleared it but if I send the project to apple with the Test project in the app, will it be a problem?

Comment: You should fix the errors (otherwise how will you run your app?). But to answer your question, Apple doesn't care whether or not you have Test project. As I said above it's 100% optional. I regularly ship apps that do not have the Test project.